# validate multiple directories in one deployment with the Salesforce CLI

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli

I use this command

> sfdx force:source:deploy -p ./foundation/,./sales,./marketing -c

because I have my metadata organized in 3 different folders. When I run this command, the Salesforce Cli does 3 separate validation deployments. First foundation, then sales, then marketing. Where I'm running into problems is ./foundation has metadata in it that ./sales needs to pass validation. My guess is because ./foundation was only validated and never deployed, ./sales doesn't see the metadata in the org for when it attempts to validate.

Is there a way to validate all the folders at once into one deployment?

Here is my sfdx-project.json

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
      {
          "path": "foundation",
          "default": true
      },
      {
           "path": "sales"
      },      
      {
          "path": "marketing"
      }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "51.0"
}
```

Comment: Are the any common components? If not then does writing a script to combine the directories in temp folder and validate that suits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Specify Unpackaged Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_unpackaged_md.htm) for deployment purposes, but, as far as I can tell, you can't specify multiple paths. As long as you only need one dependency, it should be fine to write it as such. It's probably better to just create new versions as you go along, because you can always deprecate/delete package versions. They're not permanent in any real sense. That's what dependencies were made for.

---

```
  "packageDirectories": [
      {
          "path": "foundation",
          "default": true
      },
      {
           "path": "sales",
           "dependencies": [
                { "package": "foundation",
                  "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                }
            ]
      },      
      {
          "path": "marketing"
      }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "51.0"
}
```

---

```
  "packageDirectories": [
      {
          "path": "foundation",
          "default": true
      },
      {
           "path": "sales",
           "unpackagedMetadata": { 
               "path": "foundation" 
          }
      },      
      {
          "path": "marketing"
      }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "51.0"
}
```

Comment: I don't think one unpackaged directory can make another unpackaged directory a dependency. I just tried what you suggested and the deployment is failing

Comment: @TylerZika Right, you would need to actually make a version of each package for dependencies. You should, however, be able to use one directory as a unpackaged metadata of another directory. Is there a reason why you're not creating packages?